# Formula that adds years based on results

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm trying to build an Excel spreadsheet that can convert a y/n answer into a number which can then be reflected on a date.

I have 4 columns-

- Date
- Radiation
- Shrapnel
- File saved til date

The date column shows a date of a test. The second column needs to reflect whether they need a radiation test (y/n answer). The third column needs to reflect whether they need a shrapnel test (y/n answer) and the final column shows a file saved date which is determined by the previous answers.

Imagine the date is 01/01/2010

- If radiation is ticked "Y", then you need to add 50 years to the above date.
- If shrapnel is ticked "Y", then you need to add 20 years to the above date.
- If both are ticked "Y", radiation takes priority and add 50 years to the date (not 50+20).
- If neither are ticked "N", then you can only add 10 years.

Hope I've explained it correctly. Any help would be great.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried any formula yourself already? If so, which one was the closest to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

try

=EDATE(A2,IF(B2="y",50,IF(C2="y",20,10))*12)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date is column A formatted as date 01/01/2010 then criteria radiation in B and Shrapnel in C the answer (this formula) is placed in D (but could be anywhere) cells for the result need to be formatted as number with no decimal places.

Any problems let me know, hope to have helped :)

```
=IF(AND(B2="Y",C2="Y"),YEAR(A2)+50,IF(AND(B2="Y",C2="N"),YEAR(A2)+50,IF(AND(B2="N",C2="Y"),YEAR(A2)+20,YEAR(A2)+10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep `IF` functions in Excel as simple as possible. They can get very complicated so in this case I think using a combination of `MAX` and `IF` is a cleaner approach.

```
=EDATE([@Date],MAX(IF([@Radiation]="Y",50,10),IF([@Shrapnel]="Y",20,10))*12)
```

This gives this result:

```
+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
|   |     A      |     B     |    C     |          D          |
+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| 1 | Date       | Radiation | Shrapnel | File saved til date |
| 2 | 2010-01-01 | N         | N        | 2020-01-01          |
| 3 | 2010-01-01 | Y         | N        | 2060-01-01          |
| 4 | 2010-01-01 | N         | Y        | 2030-01-01          |
| 5 | 2010-01-01 | Y         | Y        | 2060-01-01          |
+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

NB: I've used ISO date format as a matter of removing ambiguity, however it doesn't matter for the data given and the results produced in this question.